# MySQL Database - Capacity planning dilemma, advice please

Tags: php, mysql, crystal-reports, cron, report

I have a MySQL hosting and capacity planning question. I would like to know the minimum hosting requirements to host a MySQL database of the type and size described below:

**Background**: I have a customer in the finance industry who has bought a *bespoke* software CMS platform written in PHP with a MySQL database.

Their current solution does not have any reports, and the software vendor who provided it only allows them to use some PHP pages to export the entire contents of tables which the customer then has to manually manipulate in Excel to obtain their business reporting.

> **The vendor will not allow them access to their live database in order
>   to run Crystal Reports saying that this is a risk to the database, preferring them to purchase an expensive database replication solution**; so the
>   customer continues to perform tedious manual exports of entire tables
>   every day.

**The database:** The database is currently 90MB in size and a custom 9 month old PHP solution sits on top of it. The customer has no access to this as it is hosted by their current vendor. There are 43 tables in total, of which one - a whopping big log table uses up 99% of the database size.

The top four tables sizes containing the business data are tiny tables;

- 34.62 MB
- 13.79 MB
- 8.46 MB
- 7.59 MB

The vast majority of the tables are simple look-up tables for data values and have only a few rows.

The largest table in the database, however, is a big-ass log table which is 1400MB in size. This table alone accounts for over 99.9% of the total database size.

**The question:** Considering that the solution is (log table notwithstanding) very small, with only a few staff members making data entry via some simple PHP forms, is there a realistic problem with running Crystal Reports against such a database in production? Bearing in mind that there are times during the day - the majority of the day in fact - when this database is simply not being used. Lunchtimes for example and out of hours.

The vendor maintains that there is a fundamental risk to the business to query live data and that running Crystal Reports against this database could cause it to "crash the live db and the business loses operations".

The customer is keen to have a live dashboard too; which could be written with a very small SQL query to aggregate some numbers from those small tables listed above.

I usually work with SQL Server and Oracle and I have absolutely no qualms about allowing a Crystal Report or running a view to populate a UI with some real time data from the live database - especially a database this small; after all what is the database for if one cannot SELECT from it now and again?

**Is it necessary, to avoid "hanging the server" and to "avoid querying when other operations are occurring on the server", to replicate this MySQL database to a second, reporting database? In my experience, the need to do this only applies to sensitive, security-risk or databases with high transactional volumes.**

**System usage:** The system is heavily reliant on scheduled CRON jobs every half hour. There may be 500 users per week each logging on and entering some data (but not much data - see table sizes above).

Any comments are warmly welcome.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: For some reason the vendor is full of ...candy.Probably just somebody who doesnt know much about databases or backups takes the decisions.Just a speculation,not very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Mihai, My belief was once stated by Upton Sinclair, "It is difficult to get a man to understand something, when his salary depends on his not understanding it". The current vendor wishes to charge for something!!!

It doesn't matter though, I'd just like some thoughts on my question above, especially in bold re: hanging the server, running reports on a live production database and whether this poses an arguable risk? I assert that it does not, and that there is no risk of crashing a database server with querying a live MySQL database with or without Crystal Reports. Exaggerated risk.

Answer (score 2):

1) You need 2 $5 digital ocean servers.

2) "crash the live db and the business loses operations". Is absolutely false. They are idiots. What they are likely hiding is the poor structure of their database. They likely have 1 table architecture for all of their clients only separating from a client_id. Giving access to the table would give access to all of the client data which is why they force a giant replication solution so they can make sure you are only getting YOUR data.

3) Is it necessary, to avoid "hanging the server" and to "avoid querying when other operations are occurring on the server"? Yes it is.

4) to replicate this MySQL database to a second, reporting database? Yes this is good practice as you can setup fail over in the event that the worst happens. If you are really paranoid you can setup remote fail over from different companies. seeing as how this is in the financial sector I am pretty sure you want that.

5) In my experience, the need to do this only applies to sensitive, security-risk or databases with high transactional volumes. In my experience it is always good to have your data backed up because sh*t happens in life and usually when you least expect it.

As for your real-time usage. Assuming the database is structured properly with indexes and using InnoDB you should have minimal issues supporting 100 requests per second, so I think your 500 a week user problem is something to not worry about.

Like i had mentioned what you likely want is 2 servers at different providers, likely the cheapest instances you can get since you don't need a huge amount of space or resources. You can setup DNS to make 1 the primary and 1 the replication slave, then in a disaster scenario change the DNS and make the other one the master.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful comments. I have just one follow-up question for you. If 2) is absolutely false, then why is 3) necessary? Surely running some simple reports and extremely light SELECT (mostly summing values between date ranges) statements is not going to necessitate the need for database replication of essentially only 120MB/year of data?

Comment: Running a report should never "crash the database". At worst, it should only be possible to make it unavailable for as long as the report runs. Unfortunately, it is technically possible to corrupt a database in this scenario (a "transaction" is in progress, the server becomes overloaded, the front-end times out and drops the transaction *without rolling back*) but this would indicate a laughable design flaw.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the transactions that much unless you are flushing the tables with Read Write lock. But since u are using transactions the users will just wait for the locks to disappear (will see some lag in the case of the transaction taking awhile). But with the data being offline, ie not on the server and then they upload it , I forsee data sync issues. It really should be done in real time or you are going to run into a lot of issues of He overwrote my changes.

Comment: Thanks Lucky, I cannot comment on how the actual PHP system works - all I have access to is a clone of the database. No access to the PHP source code, so anything I can say is merely speculation. I don't even know if there are any transactions. Probably not, the vendor has only raised concerns about CRON jobs, presumably something in there is possibly prone to data integrity issues when the server gets busy. Who knows? There's no data sync, if anything there would only be a duplicate database for reporting only; but would running Crystal Reports at the same time as a transaction be a problem?

Comment: All the transaction will do is pause the crystal report query from executing until its finished.

Comment: Thanks Lucky, I thought as much. It's a possible performance issue not a data reliability or operational problem. I will advise my client that a replicated database is preferable (and extremely cheap to arrange, albeit not hosted in their current data centre at these advertised rates), but certainly not essential. Thanks!

Comment: Well if we assume that the transaction was programmed properly there wont be any data reliability problems... If you don't do it correctly then there will be.... just to further clarify haha.